# Running many websites on one server

Tags: apache

This may be a duplicate question, but i have been thinking about it for long. I know, apache supports hosting many websites on a single server. But i want to know the implementation.

The server will have the single IP address. TCP is always port 80. Then how is it possible to run 10 different websites on a single machine. Also DNS, has one-to-one mapping.

I am thinking, probably some tweaking is done in HTTP protocol, but cant think of exact and best possible solution .

Thanks

Comment: *This may be a duplicate question, but i have been thinking about it for long.* -- you probably should have spent more time with the search function / google then.

Comment: There has to be some mechanism to discriminate between different websites.  If port 80 is the only port you are using, and you are only using one DNS name, what are your expectations as to how the server is going to land HTTP requests among the different sites?

Comment: DNS is actually a many-to-many mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add many `VirtualHost` entries in your Apache config as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.tld
ServerAlias domain.tld *.domain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.otherdomain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain
</VirtualHost>
```

This basically prompts Apache to respond differently, serving different documents based on which domain was requested.

More information can be found in the Apache docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: From the question it wasn't clear if there was one DNS name or multiple names, if multiple names this is the right answer.

Comment: That's true: I figured that it must be multiple domains if the IP address and port are always the same, which he did mention.

Comment: Well, if one were running multiple Rails applications for example, you can use the same port and DNS name, but still direct traffic to separate "applications", like http://serverfault.com/questions/405688/multiple-rails-apps-on-same-subdomain.

Comment: Thanks, Virtual Host is the answer. I needed the implementaion of virtual host, which is done by specifying host field in the http header.